# Как правильно согласовать?

Tags: согласование

1. Каталог обновлен в соответствии с актуальным ассортиментом.
2. Каталог обновлен в соответствие с актуальным ассортиментом.
3. Каталог обновлен соответственно актуальному ассортименту.

Comment: @Izum4ik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, правилен первый вариант: Каталог обновлен в соответствии с актуальным ассортиментом. Здесь производный предлог "в соответствии с"

Comment: Если речь только о согласовании - только "в соответствии" -  в чём? Но вот я бы сказала "в соответствии с актуальнОСТЬЮ ассортимента". Утрачена актуальность - каталог изменён, а то получается, что каталог изменяется, когда присылают новый перечень (ассортимент), который является актуальным.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо правильного первого варианта, возможен такой:

Каталог приведён  в соответстви**е** с обновившимся ассортиментом.

Comment: Тогда уж "Ассортимент приведён в соответствие( чему?) спросу покупателей". Каталог - это перечень, бумага, её переписывают, заменяют в соответствии с актуальностью(востребованностью) товара, имеющегося в наличии. Ассортимент - наличие товаров, это не список, это само наличие, разнообразие.По-вашему получается, что изменили каталог, потому что изменили состав товара в наличии,а почему? Ушла мысль об актуальности . Речь идёт именно о замене товаров, а значит и  каталога в связи с изменением спроса, востребованности, т.е. актуальности.Это термин.

Comment: Не знаю точных намерений рекламщиков фирмы, но предположил, что в связи с обновившимся ассортиментом прежний каталог потерял с ним связь, и под "актуальным" подразумевался фактически имеющийся изменённый ассортимент (это слово иногда применяют в таком смысле, близком к английскому: "фактически имеющий место"). Если так, то эта фраза обращает внимание на то, что появилось что-то новое и в новом каталоге это отражено.

С падежами сложнее (попадаются разные толкования), но у Ушакова есть такое:

Привести что-нибудь в соответствие с чем-нибудь.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1035374